# Live Tiles in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Is it possible in visual studio for windows phone / C# that we can configure the application tile only.
That is ..
No Maain Page.xaml or anything.
The tile will keep on changing its background with every second of time.
Or on clicking it just a phone function will be Activated/Deactivated. (eg Bluetooth)

Please Help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Tiles always open a specific page in your app. if you leave the page the default page will be opened.

Also changing the background or updating the tile can be done in a background agent at a maximum amount of once every 30 minutes.

[More info on live tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Take a look at the "Connectivity shortcuts" app in the marketplace. they do link to specific settings screens but they can not switch the value by clicking it.

Comment: I need one more help..

Is there any code to lock the phone..??

Comment: Could you accept the answer if this answer helped you. what do you need more?

Comment: @GeertvdC : Is it possible to disable Hardware start Button while application is running like we can disable Hardware back button ?\

Comment: no you can't and you can also not disable the back button. you can catch the back event but discarding this event will make your application fail the marketplace requirements. also search button can't be disabled aswell.